# Navigation Bar Title changes when scrolling

Tags: swift, uitableview, uinavigationbar

Hi I've searched the web quite a while for this issue now, but it seems like theres a bug in my UITableViewController where when I scroll, the navigation bar title changes depending on where I scroll.

Pic 1
[image]

Pic 2
[image]

**UPDATE:** I included my table view controller code because I'm not sure where it could've gone wrong. I don't directly modify the navigation title in this code as I can do it directly in the storyboard.

It seems like when I run the code, the correct title appears briefly and once the data loads, the title begins to change weirdly according to the data.

```
class CustomCollectionsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    // Mark: Variables
    var collections = [Collection]()
    var currentCollectionID:String!
    
    // Mark: IBOutlet
    @IBOutlet var collectionsTableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Mark: Delegate
        collectionsTableView.delegate = self;
        
        // Mark: Datasource
        collectionsTableView.dataSource = self;
        
        let url = "www.url.com"
        
        ClientService.getCollections(url: url) { (receivedCollections) in
            
            self.collections = receivedCollections
            self.collectionsTableView?.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return self.collections.count
    }

    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "collectionTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionTableViewCell
        
        title = self.collections[indexPath.row].name
        
        cell.collectionTitle.text = title
        

        return cell
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "displayProducts" {
            
            if let indexPath = collectionsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
                var destinationVC = segue.destination as! CollectionViewController
                let id = collections[indexPath.row].id
                currentCollectionID = String(id)
                destinationVC.collectionID = currentCollectionID

            }      
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You probably set your title to something else, probably in cellForRowAt, or scrollViewDidScroll kind of methods. Share your code, so we can understand whats going on better

Comment: Do the words "Ergonomic" or "Synergistic" appear in the data or in code?  Speaking of code, what's that look like?

Comment: @danh I've updated the post to include my table view controller code. The words Ergonomic and Synergistic do appear but as data that is retrieved.

Comment: @emrepun I've shared the code, thank you.

Comment: Yeah as I suspected, you set your title in cellForRowAt method, check the answer below.

Comment: that worked! I didn't realize that would directly set the title. thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "collectionTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionTableViewCell

    title = self.collections[indexPath.row].name

    cell.collectionTitle.text = title


    return cell
}
```

you are changing the page title in this function
this line of code

```
 title = self.collections[indexPath.row].name
```

changes the page title
I rewrite the function for you to this:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "collectionTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionTableViewCell

    let temp = self.collections[indexPath.row].name

    cell.collectionTitle.text = temp


    return cell
}
```

Comment: To be a little more complete on "why", `UITableViewController` inherits from `UIViewController`.  The latter has a `title` property which the OP code inadvertently (by not declaring it as a local variable) sets.  The `UIViewController` behavior -- when it's a child vc of a `UINavigationController` is to have its `title` setter set the 'title` of the navigation controller, which in turn sets the title label text in its title bar.  The fix, as this answer points out correctly, is to declare a local variable to hold your data's title value.